# What cygwin package contains the zipcmp command

Tags: cygwin

There is a man page for zipcmp command at http://polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=ZIPCMP&tf=2&of=Cygwin&sf=1. However, I cannot find which Cygwin package contains it at https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=zip&arch=x86_64.

Comment: Try posting on the cygwin mailing list (found on cygwin.com).

Answer (score 0):

as reported on: 
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libzip-tools/libzip-tools-1.5.1-1

the tool and manual is available on `libzip-tools` package.

No idea why the search is missing the files